# Positioning the top left corner of a transform: scaled element at exactly the same location as it'd be without transform

Tags: css, transform

When scaling up an element using transform, the location of its corners changes. I want the position of its top left corner to remain identical. I tried to use `transform-origin` for that and got some improvement but it's still not the same location:

```
.logo {
  transform: scale(1.25);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: please share a fiddle with an example of the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.logo{
transform:scale(1.25);
transform-origin:top left;
}

p{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<p>Before</p>
<div><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
<p>After</p>
<div class="logo"><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
```